# How app can get PayPal user transaction info?

Tags: paypal, transactions, oauth-2.0, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Can I get notification with data at specific url when users who connected PayPal to my app throught Oauth2 will get payment? I know it possible with IPN, but then each user need to add my url in their account settings. Is any another way?

Update: Or can I manually get information about last user transactions(completed outside my app)?

Comment: So you want to retrieve the transactions from the different PayPal accounts ?

Comment: Thaks for response. I want to retrieve transaction info when a third party send payment to PayPal account of user of my app. But it seems impossible without setting IPN url by user of my app. Only way is send manual request with [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish what you're trying to do, I think.

You mentioned IPN, and that would be the best way.  You can specify the NotifyURL in your standard button code or API requests (depending on how you're setting up the payments) so that IPNs for those payments will be sent to your IPN URL.  That way you don't have to have users set that up in their own account.

Alternatively (or in conjunction with), you could use the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#permissions) to allow users to authenticate your app to make API calls on their behalf.  Then you can use the [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) and [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) APIs to pull any info you need about their account transaction history.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The second way seems good enough. Only need to put this request in cron.